# Laravel + x-editable: Integrity constraint violation 1048: no data passed

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, x-editable

Using x-editable to create an editable form that sends requests via ajax. The form looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="editable editable-click" id="mileage" 
        data-name="mileage" 
        data-type="number" 
        data-pk="{{ $car->id }}" 
        data-original-title="Enter mileage">
    {{ $car->mileage }}
</a>
```

Then goes the JS:

```
$('#mileage').editable({
  url: '{{ route('changeMileage', $car->id) }}',
  type: 'number',
  pk: {{ $car->id }},
  name: 'mileage',
  title: 'Enter mileage in km',
  validate:function(value){
    if ($.trim(value) === '') {
      return "Field is required";
    }
  }
})
```

In my controller:

```
$car = Car::where('id', $id)->first();

$this->validate($request, [
        'value' => 'number|min:' . $car->mileage . '|max:999999',
]);

$car->update([$car->mileage => $request->value]);
```

The controller code is a bit messed because I tried different versions of it. Just because I need to validate (entered mileage can not be less then existing one).

But the problem is that once I send the request, I got the `Integrity constraint violation: 1048` error, that says that the `mileage` field is empty. Running `dd($request->value)` gives me `null`, but monitoring the request from the browser, it goes as intended: `name=mileage&value=325000&pk=1`.

Somehow the controller is missing the `value` value. Any solutions, please?

P.S. I intentionally did not check for `pk` value, because I have only one field to edit on the current page that already has the `id` information.

P.P.S. I tried every method I could imagine - `dd($request->all())` still returns an empty array - [].

Comment: I doubt laravel uses dynamic properties ... I suggest to use `$request->input('value');`

Comment: Still no luck. Been there, done that. `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, even if x-editable is abandoned, it works. With help from other developers, I came up with that solution.

In my JavaScript code, added the following line after every other options:

```
ajaxOptions: {
  dataType: 'json'
},
```

Before that, in the same JS file, added a line to set up the ajax headers:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "X-CSRF-Token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
  },
});
```

In Controller added a check to see if the request is sent via ajax:

```
if($request->ajax()) {
  $car->update(['mileage' => $request->input('value')]);
  return response()->json(['success' => true]);
}
```

And the request now goes as follows: `name=mileage&value=325002&pk=1`

After that, it works like a charm!